# In Ruby, how do I check if method "foo=()" is defined?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

In Ruby, I can define a method `foo=(bar)`:

```
irb(main):001:0> def foo=(bar)
irb(main):002:1>   p "foo=#{bar}"
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
```

Now I'd like to check if it has been defined,

```
irb(main):004:0> defined?(foo=)
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):4: syntax error, unexpected ')'
 from (irb):4
 from :0
```

What is the proper syntax to use here?  I assume there must be a way to escape `foo=` such that it is parsed and passed correctly to the `defined?` operator.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The problem is that the `foo=` method is designed to be used in assignments. You can use `defined?` in the following way to see what's going on:

```
defined?(self.foo=())
#=> nil
defined?(self.foo = "bar")
#=> nil

def foo=(bar)
end

defined?(self.foo=())
#=> "assignment"
defined?(self.foo = "bar")
#=> "assignment"
```

Compare that to:

```
def foo
end

defined?(foo)
#=> "method"
```

To test if the `foo=` method is defined, you should use [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000331) instead:

```
respond_to?(:foo=)
#=> false

def foo=(bar)
end

respond_to?(:foo=)
#=> true
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem.  I'm still curious to know if there's a way to escape foo= such that it can be fed to defined? but at least now I can move on.

Comment: The problem here is that `foo=` is always used in assignments, so Ruby will return `"assignment"` if you test for `defined? foo()` (see updated answer).

Answer (score 50):

You can check if a method exists by using the `respond_to?` method, and you pass it a symbol, e.g. `bar.respond_to?(:foo=)` to see if the object `bar` has a method `foo=`. If you want to know if instances of a class respond to a method you can use `method_defined?` on the class (or module), e.g. `Foo.method_defined?(:bar=)`.

`defined?` isn't a method, but an operator which returns a description of the operand (or nil if it is not defined, which is why it can be used in an if statement). The operand can be any expression, i.e. a constant, a variable, an assignment, a method, a method call, etc. The reason why it doesn't work when you do `defined?(foo=)` is because of the parentheses, skip them and it should work more or less as expected. That being said, `defined?` is a pretty weird operator, and no one uses it to test for the existence of methods.

Comment: It is respond_to?, not responds_to?

Comment: Ah, the spelling of Ruby core library... `respond_to?`, `start_with?`, `end_with?`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280556/why-does-ruby-use-respond-to-instead-of-responds-to has a nice explanation of the choice behind the naming TL;DR `you.knock if you.respond_to?(:knock)`