# Why does Ruby use respond_to? instead of responds_to?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions, introspection

I'm curious why Ruby's introspection related method to check if an object responds to a method is `respond_to?` instead of `responds_to?`

It always seems awkward to me but maybe that's because I'm used to `respondsToSelector` in objective-c.

Comment: Maybe it's trying to be imperative: hey you object, RESPOND TO!

Comment: I can't believe this question hasn't been asked before!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Matz [prefers](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/18951) second person singular or third person plural:

> "responds_to?" probably makes more
>   sense to English speakers than 
>   "respond_to?".
>
> Maybe.  But I'm Japanese.  Ruby is not
>   English.  It's the basic naming rule
>   to avoid third person singular form in
>   the standard libraries.
>
> ```
>   you = Human.new
>   if you.respond_to?(:knock)
>     ...
>   end
> ```

Comment: I believe it's not that Matz prefers second person singular or third person plural, but he prefers the default (to-less infinitive) form of a verb.

Comment: @sawa like the "dictionary form" (if that's the correct term for 辞書形) of Japanese verbs?

Comment: Yes. But Japanese does not have person-number agreement, so there is no difference in Japanese. It is usually called 終止形 (the ending form).

Comment: Why not both `respond_to?` and `responds_to?`? Ruby has a bunch of methods that are aliased like this.

Comment: @Nate Why not `responding_to?`, `responded_to?` in addition to that?

Comment: @Sawa, to me those kind of sound more like event handler names.

Comment: There's no guarantee the subject preceding `respond_to` is singular.  It could a collection (eg `Array`, `Set`).  So trying to achieve grammatical agreement is pointless.  `respond_to` is shorter than `responds_to`.  So why get into the verb conjugation business, which is only a feature of certain natural languages?

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with a construction in English where `responds_to?` actually makes sense and is proper. Grammatically correct: "Does it `respond_to?` :bar"; "Does foo `respond_to` :bar?". Only by casting the indicative "Foo `responds_to` :bar" to an ersatz interrogative—"Foo `responds_to` :bar?" does it make any sense, and that is definitely taking liberties with the language. Long story short—`respond_to?` would be correct even if being English-like were the primary consideration.

Comment: I always think in my head "[wait!] foo responds_to :bar???" that's well formed spoken English, but only if you intonate the phrase in the form of a question.  It's helpful remembering that it's shorter without the 's' and so maybe I will not have to google this again :)

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey The most common use I have for the method looks like this: `if my_object.respond_to?(:with_indifferent_access) ...  else ...  end`. Clearly `responds_to` is more grammatically correct here. However I understand Matz's logic

Comment: you.responds_to? makes more sense anyway.  ruby got this one incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

How do you know that the receiver is always third person singular? It is possible that the receiver be `I`, `we`, `you`, or `they`, or some other thing that represents plurality. In that case, will you still say that `responds_to?` is more natural than `respond_to?`? In order to preserve generality, it is better to name a method in a form as general as possible. Rather than naming a method in third person singular, it makes more sense to name it in the default, *to*-less infinitive form, which is also used in dictionaries.

Comment: I guess I always think of the receiver as 'it'.