# How to check if private method is defined in ruby

Tags: ruby, class

The closest I can find is [In Ruby, how do I check if method "foo=()" is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348521/in-ruby-how-do-i-check-if-method-foo-is-defined), but it only works if the method is public, even when inside the class block.

What I want:

```
class Foo
  private

  def bar
    "bar"
  end

  magic_private_method_defined_test_method :bar #=> true
end
```

What I've tried:

```
class Foo
  private

  def bar
    "bar"
  end

  respond_to? :bar #=> false
  #this actually calls respond_to on the class, and so respond_to :superclass gives true
  defined? :bar #=> nil
  instance_methods.include?(:bar) #=> false
  methods.include?(:bar) #=> false
  method_defined?(:bar) #=> false
  def bar
    "redefined!"
  end # redefining doesn't cause an error or anything

  public
  def bar
    "redefined publicly!"
  end #causes no error, behaves no differently whether or not #bar had been defined previously
end
```

Comment: Side note: I was *actually* wondering this and discovered the answer in the course of writing the question. Posted here since I couldn't easily find my answer and so I hope the next bloke will be able to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want `Module#private_method_defined?`.

```
class Foo
  def do_stuff_if_bar_is_defined
    if self.class.private_method_defined?(:bar)
      do_stuff
    end
  end

  private

  def bar
    "bar"
  end

  private_method_defined? :bar #=> true
end
Foo.private_method_defined? :bar #=> true
```

Answer (score 65):

Another way is to use `:respond_to?`, e.g.

```
self.respond_to?(:bar, true)
```

Note that the second parameter is important here - it denotes that `:respond_to?` should look for all scope methods including private methods.