# In a Ruby module, how do you test if a method exists in the context which use the module?

Tags: ruby, reflection, dsl

## Some context

I'm playing with Ruby to deepen my knowledge and have fun while at the same time improving my knowledge of Esperanto with a just starting toy project called *[Ĝue](https://github.com/psychoslave/gxue)*. Basically, the aim is to use Ruby facilities to implement a DSL that matches Esperanto traits that I think interesting in the context of a programming language.

## The actual problem

So a first trait I would like to implement is inflection of verbs, using infinitive in method declaration (ending with -i), and [jussive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussive_mood) (ending with -u) for call to the method.

A first working basic implementation is like that:

```
module Ĝue
  def method_missing(igo, *args, &block)
    case igo
    when /u$/
      celo = igo.to_s.sub(/u$/, 'i').to_s
      send(celo)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

And it works. Now the next step is to make it more resilient, because there is no guaranty that `celo` will exists when the module try to call it. That is, the module should implement the `respond_to?` method. Thus the question, how do the module know if the context where module was required include the corresponding infinitive method? Even after adding `extend self` at the beginning of the module, inside of the module `methods.include? :testi` still return `false` when tested with the following code, although the `testu` call works perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require './teke/ĝue.rb'
include Ĝue
def testi; puts 'testo!' ;end
testu
```

Note that the test is run directly into the `main` scope. I don't know if this makes any difference with using a dedicated class scope, I would guess that no, as to the best of my knowledge everything is an object in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution through [In Ruby, how do I check if method "foo=()" is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348521/in-ruby-how-do-i-check-if-method-foo-is-defined#2348524)

So in this case, this would be checkable through

```
eval("defined? #{celo}") == 'method'
```

Comment: It's not yet completely right actually. It fact, it seems that as is, `defined?` will returns 'method' anytime `celo` have a `to_s` method. First I meant `to_sym`, and even with that it won't work. The argument should be the identfier corresponding to the `celo` string.

Comment: Fixed the problem in the anwer